# create a class for painting markers in google maps api v2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, markers

i'm trying to do a class which is used to paint few markers in a map. I have a problem, but this problem is a Java problem no a Android problem.

I have a main class that instantiates a helper class that defines the methods for painting the markers:

```
private GoogleMap mapa = null;
private MostrarBares pintaBares; //helper class

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tapas);

    mapa = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapaTapas)).getMap();
    mapa.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
    mapa.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this);

    if(todos == true)
        pintaBares.addTodosMap(mapa);
    .....
```

Now, i write the helper class:

```
public class MostrarBares {
    public void addNo11OnMap(GoogleMap map)
    {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
          .position(new LatLng(40.656106,-4.691306))
          .title("El No.11 La Taberna")
         .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.no11)));
    }

    public void addTodosMap(GoogleMap map)
    {
      addNo11OnMap(map);
    }
}
```

When the method pintaBares.addTodosMap(mapa) is called it throws null pointer exception ... what is the problem?

if i would want to implement the methods

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) 
{
    Toast.makeText(this, marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    return(false);
}

@Override
public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

where do i should implement these? In main class or helper class?

Thank's you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
private MostrarBares pintaBares; //helper class
```

to

```
private MostrarBares pintaBares = new MostrarBares(); //helper class
```

You need to have an objects on which you call methods.